# using sed to match multiple substrings and replace

Tags: sed

In bash I'm looking for a way to update a line in a file:

```
/dev/vg/home /home ext4  defaults,noatime,nofail,nodev 0 2
```

if line contains '/home ext4' replace 'nodev', with 'nodev,nosuid' :

```
/dev/vg/home /home ext4  defaults,noatime,nofail,nodev,nosuid 0 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if line contains '/home ext4' replace 'nodev', with 'nodev,nosuid' :

```
sed '/\/home.*ext4/s/nodev/nodev,nosuid/'
```

If a line matches `/home<anything>ext4` then substitute 'nodev', with 'nodev,nosuid'.

Comment: You have backticks, `\``, around your command, you probably want single quotes, `'`, no?

Comment: @MikeQ you may also like match whitespaces `/\/home[[:space:]]*ext4/` or spaces with tabs `/\/home[ \t]*ext4` would be probably better regexes.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
sed '/\/home ext4/s/nodev/nodev,nosuid/g'  Input_file
```

OR choosing a different separator as `#` rather than default `/` to avoid confusions, since your keyword `/home ext4` has a `/` in it which we need to escape to let `sed` know that it is not a separator and its a value of string, so in spite of escaping things we can use a different separator itself.

```
sed '\#/home ext4#s/nodev/&,nosuid/' Input_file
```

If you see above solution carefully we need not to escape `/` since `sed`'s separator is `#` here,  btw you could choose it as per your convenience too. Thanks to @potong sir for guiding on right regex for this code.

Comment: The second solution is not quite right. The first separator for the regexp address (other than the default `/`) must be quoted (unlike the separators for a substitution command) i.e. `sed '\#/home ext4#s/nodev/&,nosuid/' file`

Comment: @potong, Thank you sir for letting know, I have changed it as per guidance, please do lemme know in case of any further edit, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Yeah I noticed a problem but couldn't figure it out. However it was perfect timing because I needed it again and this updated solution worked well for me. Thank you ! PS Upvote potong .

Answer (score 1):

The following is untested.

The sed command gives the substitute command on any line that contains /home ext4.

```
sed -i '/\/home ext4/s/nodev/nodev,nosuid/' /path/to/file
```